# Why does ListView ignore constraints

Tags: flutter

Why does a ListView completely ignore imposed constraints?

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      child: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 500),
        child: ListView(
          children: buildList(data),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The displayed ListView does not seem to be bothered at all with the `maxWidth:500` of the parent container (same if replaced with a ConstrainedBox) and all elements (which are Rows) go full screen width.

Why?

The solution is to work with width of children instead, but still I'd much rather constrain the entire listView, and also  if there's a constraint, shouldn't everything inside be forced not to exceed it?

EDIT: After hours of trying various things it finally works. Turns out the list view needed to a child of a Center, otherwise it would not pay any attention to SizedBoxes, ConstrainedBoxes, Containers etc. you'd put on it or its children and stretch full screen no matter what.

Comment: check [Understanding constraints](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints) , also see `Example 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14`

Comment: Thanks, but don't these examples show exactly that the child should be forced to respect the constraints imposed by the parent? In my case the parent imposes a 500 maxWidth constraint whereas the child ListView goes well beyond that to the full screen width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the parent widgets of the `Padding(child: Container(... list view ))`? I mean are you sure that a parent is not imposing its constraints on its children? Try do replace your ListView with `Container(color: Colors.red, height: 100)` and see if it respects the constraints. If it does not, there probably is a parent widget with infinite width constraint or something like that!

A solution can be wrap your Container with an UnconstrainedBox but I would recommend first checking my first point :D

Comment: It's top level on the page - no weird additional parents. The problem is the ListView ignores the immediate constraint of 500 and goes way wider. I'm not sure if a higher level parent would override or somehow cancel out this constraint.

Comment: Well try UnconstrainedBox(child: Padding(
      child: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 500),
        child: ListView(
          children: buildList(data),
        ),
      ),
    )); And check if it works

Comment: Wrapping in an UnconstrainedBox on the list item does not change anything. Doing so with the whole list (be it within or outside the constrained container) results in a bunch of no-size errors (kinda expected?). But still I think there's something wrong here - simply setting a width on a ListView surely shouldn't require workarounds or counteracting other constraints?

Comment: IT WORKS. Turns out I needed to wrap a Center around the ListView. I'll look for why this is the case but not too much to maintain sanity. Probably it's the same principle as you suggested with the UnconstrainedBox; only that the latter couldn't be used here due to lack of outer constraints (so it would expand indefinitely) - so picking as solved answer. Thanks!